# Preventing mid-item line breaks in a list in a table

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-word-2007

It's not programming, but it's the paperwork you have to fill out ot get things to program.

When you have a list with an item that's two lines long, and text above pushes it down such that a page break should fall between the two lines, Word pushes the item down so that both lines are on the following page - this is called *Widow/Orphan Control* and is an option on the *Paragraph* menu.

When the list is inside of a table cell, however, this feature doesn't seem to work - which is what I'm looking to work around. Word doesn't push the item down automatically, so it breaks across two pages, as seen here:

[image: Breaking where it shouldn't]

Solutions that have been tried:

- Playing with the options on the *Paragraph* tab: doesn't seem to do anything
- Changing the margins or text: this is a template and will need to always work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify new formating rules for the row.

1. Select the offending Row.
2. Right-Click and select **Table
   Properties** from the dropdown menu.
3. Click the **Row** tab.
4. **Uncheck** *Allow row to break Across pages*

That will do it. It has the added benefit of preserving Header rows across multiple pages.

**EDIT:**

After your comment I was able to solve the problem by creating a 1 celled table inside the offending row and place there the list items. Then I follow the above procedure to set this sub-table row.

What this essentially does is keep your list as one single unit, which you can then properly format. There may there be the need for simple adjustments like preserving line spacing between the list and the remaining text. But nothing that can't be set straight with a Style definition for this single-celled table.

Comment: That causes the break to occur before the row itself, which isn't workable in this case (the row in question is about half a page long). What I'm really looking for is a way to get the functionality of Widow/Orphan Control to work within a table cell).

Comment: Ok. i'm following you. Editing my answer